# Why is the java set path property not permanent in my computer?

Tags: path

i have to type the "set path" command manually every time in the cmd. I have it on my environment variables on my computer but it doesnt work. I even tried installing and uninstalling the java but no use. 
I have this set path property on User variables as well as system variables but its not working.

My main problem is that i am trying to work out the java rmi programs which requires both system32 path and java/jdk/bin path but as i said, i  can have only one path at a time.

How can i fix it permanently so that i dont have to set path again and again in my cmd??

Comment: Your question is not very clear and is subject for interpretation, please tell us what is not working and how do you do to make it "work" and what errors do you get.

Comment: Reboot the computer and check again

Answer (score 0):

User variables get purged on reboot.

Add them to the 'Path' variable for System variables then restart cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System
2. Click on Advanced System Settings on a left bar
3. Click on Environment variables
4. Edit for you.

In images;
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Windows version you can use the [SETX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx) command.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240725/setx-doesnt-append-any-path-to-system-path-variable